# what is this function doing "if(c)" print(c), else print(c-1) checks without any relation

Tags: c, if-statement, boolean

I have seen many problems like, here I'm giving one example.
Always I wonder why is even this 'if' is given with only one variable without any relation to the other variable to check with.

```
int c = 0;
if (c)
     printf("%d",c=0);
else
    printf("%d",c=1);
print("%d\n",c);
```

Once I have seen a while condition as while(~c) for the loop to run. 
I have run this code and got 11 as the answer.

output:
11

but I don't know how will the if checks the condition with only one operand i.e., without any operators.
I expected the output as 00 but the actual output was 11.

Here I'm expecting it would be as boolean but the c here is int.

Sorry for my terrible editing, this was my first time posting a code snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The form of an `if` statement is:

```
if(expression)
```

The only condition is that the `expression` should have a [scalar type.](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/type)

In this particular case, `c` in parentheses is an expression which evaluates to `false` as its value is zero.

If you think it is not clear enough to you, you can simply write,

```
if(c != 0)
```

Comment: So, the default if statement for only one operand if(c) will be taken as if(c!=0).

Comment: Here, as `c` is an integer it will be taken that way. If it is a pointer, it will be checked to see if it not a null pointer.

Comment: what will it be for a boolean type?

Comment: For boolean, it is `if(boolVar == true)`  In general you can say if the expression compares not equal to 0, the statement under `if` is executed, otherwise `else` is executed.

Comment: can `if c:` also be used for `if c is not None:`

Comment: If `c` is an integer and `None` is `0`, it can be used like that.

Answer (score 0):

Non-zero value is evaluated as true and zero value is evaluated to false.

Answer (score 0):

The `if` statement here is truly unnecessary.

After the line `int c = 0;`, the value of `c` is `0`. The `if` statement checks its condition in the following way: if the value is `0`, the statement is deemed as false and the branch of execution is not entered. If the statement is `if-else`, then else is entered. Otherwise, the `if` branch is entered. In the case you provided, the expression `c` is evaluated to `0`, so the `else` branch is taken.

As for the value printed, the statement `printf("%d",ex);` will print the value of the expression `ex`, interpreted as a decimal integer value to the standard output. In your case, the expression is `c=1`. This is an assignment expression, which always evaluated to the value being assigned. The value of `c` changing is a side effect. Therefore, `printf("%d",c=1);` prints `1` to the standard output and, afterwards, the value of the variable `c` is 1. The `print("%d\n",c);` which follows prints `1` to the standard output, followed by a newline character.

Answer (score 0):

The if statement syntax is

**if(expression)**

Here, expression refers to the result of the evaluation of the condition.

In this case, 
`if(c)`
The implicit conversion will be like,

```
if(0)
```

So the condition fails, and it gets into the else case.

In the else case,

```
printf("%d",c=1);
```

The evaluation will takes place in the order of assigning c=1 first. 
The result of assignment is success with the changed value for the variable, so the result is printed as 1 in the first statement.

since the value of c is assigned to 1 , the last print statement prints the corresponding value of c.

Comment: `The result of assignment is success, so the result is printed as 1 in the first statement.` Does this mean that `printf("%d",c=13);` would print `1` as well?

Comment: The result of assignment is success with the changed value of variable, So the corresponding value will be printed. So for printf("%d",c=13);, the output would be 13. Edited the answer content. For c=13, the output of this program will be 1313

Comment: I don't see how success plays a role here. I also can't see why an assignment would fail.

Comment: Success depicts to the assignment of value to the variable, Agree to the point assignment would never fail.